# fb.Login() window closes right away and returns 'not_authorized'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have FB login enabled on my website with the FB JDK. When I use it, it works perfectly: the dialog window opens, I authorize, and the `authResponse` is as expected. When another user uses it (who has not yet authorized the app, but is logged into FB), the login dialog appears for a brief second, and instantly disappears, and the response object has status `not_authorized`. Any ideas as to why the dialog might not be asking the user to authorize?

In my layout (Haml):

```
%body
  #fb-root
  :javascript
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB._https = false;
      FB.init({
        appId      : <App ID>
        status     : true,
        cookie     : true,
        oauth      : true,
        xfbml      : true
      });
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if(window.reportFBstatus) {
          reportFBstatus(response);
        }
      }, true);
    };
    // Load the SDK
    (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
```

The login link:

```
%a{href: '#', onclick: 'FB.login(window.reportFBstatus, {scope: "user_about_me"})'}
```

In the Coffeescript:

```
window.reportFBstatus = (response) ->
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers:
      'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  })
  console.log response # always shows status=not_authorized for other users
  if response.status is 'connected'
    auth = response.authResponse
    $.post('/login', {fb_id: auth.userID, fb_token: auth.accessToken}, (data) ->
      window.currentUser = data
    )
```

Comment: I am experiencing same issue.Can't figure out the root cause

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was actually a bone-headed one--I'd forgotten to change the app from sandbox mode to live mode in [developers app console on Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) (click your app on the left). Alternatively, I could have added the people I want to be able to log in as developers or testers.

Hope that helps others!

Comment: Doh, had the same problem. Thanks for posting the answer, I would have searched hours for the solution otherwise.

Comment: I had the same problem, it was such a silly mistake on my part, thanks! I'd like this answer 20 times if I could

Comment: Doh! That /did/ help me! Thank you for posting what some might call obvious but which didn't cross my tired mind.

Comment: I encountered another cause. Facebook requires a review for apps that request anything other than the three basic permissions. If you set the scope to include an extended permission, but Facebook hasn't reviewed your app, you'll encounter this same behavior.   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

Comment: I encountered another cause. Facebook requires a review for apps that request anything other than the three basic permissions. If you set the scope to include an extended permission, but Facebook hasn't reviewed your app, you'll encounter this same behavior.   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login